# fastest way to split video into frames java

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have seen many similar questions like mine, but i have one difference i need to do this in java not in c/c++ and i need it work on android devices.

I found 1 way to do it with the "MediaMetadataRetriever".

but it takes me too long to seperate the frames(~1 sec to frame) and i need to read like 600 frames so it takes me 10 minutes only to read the images without the image processing.

I would like to know if there is another way to split the frames from a video, or manipulate MediaMetadataRetriever and make it work fast.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684347/extract-all-video-frames-in-android/43026616#43026616) answer regarding how to extract image frames from video file using ffmpeg..It's fast..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a `MediaCodec` decoder.  There are some examples [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).

In particular, if you look at the DecodeEditEncodeTest code, the `checkVideoFile()` function decodes a previously-created stream to an external texture, then manipulates it with OpenGL ES.  (To do this from a .mp4 file, you'd want to access it through a `MediaExtractor`.)

`MediaMetadataRetriever#getFrameAtTime()` is really meant for extracting thumbnails, and isn't particularly suited to extracting large numbers of frames.

**Update:** there's now [sample code](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest) for extracting video frames using `MediaExtractor`, `MediaCodec`, and GLES (API 16+).

Comment: Is there a way to download all cts classes and use it as library?
And can i convert the output to openCV matrix?

Comment: (1) Assuming the video format is supported by `MediaCodec`, all the work is done by hardware or drivers through the point where you copy the data into your buffer with `glReadPixels`.  (2) CTS is a collection of conformance tests; last I checked, the APK was about 100MB.  So you definitely don't want *all* CTS classes. :-)  Better to just pick out the parts you need.  Some of the other examples on that page (e.g. EncodeAndMuxTest) were written that way.  (3) I haven't used OpenCV; `glReadPixels` returns simple RGBA (which can be annoying if you need YUV).

Comment: Actually i need a gray scale matrix. i don't need image at all.
and after i use glReadPixels function it take again too long to calculate.

Comment: It's supported only from API level 16, do you have an idea for api level 11 and above?